# querying a polymorphic Hibernate property

Tags: java, hibernate

In my Hibernate model, I have the following classes

```
class UserFavourite {
  Entity entity
}

abstract class Entity {
  String name
}

class Foo extends Entity {}
class Bar extends Entity {}
```

How can I get all `UserFavourite` instances that have are associated with a `Foo`?

I read that a HQL query like the one below should work, but it's not working for me

```
FROM UserFavourite f
WHERE f.entity.class = Foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
select f
from UserFavourite f, Foo foo
where f.entity.id = foo.id
```